# HTML CSS JS : unable to open pop up information box when hovering over an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a project where I have to use JavaScript to open pop up boxes displaying information about each category  when I hover over specific images . I have written code to perform this specific task but
no box pops up whenever I hover over the specific images . I have my code down below .

```js
function popinfo() {
  var e = document.getElementById("horror-img"); //get image from html

  e.onmouseover = function() {
    document.getElementById('horror-pop').style.display = 'block';
  }

  e.onmouseout = function() {
    document.getElementById('horror-pop').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
#horror-pop {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div id="p-float">
  <div class="p-float">
    <div class="p-float-in">
      <center><img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\horror.jpg" alt=l ogo/ onmouseover="popinfo()" id="horror-img"><br/>
        <div class="p-name">Horror Fiction</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </center>
</div>
<div id="horror-pop"> Horror Text </div>
```

Now this example is for one image and whenever I hover my mouse over the image I get nothing . No box pops up . I am also curious about the fact that if you have for example 4 images and you want the pop up box to display different info for each image how can we dynamically use just one function to display a different text for each image ?

I would appreciate your help with the issues above . Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML code

```
<div id ="p-float">  
 <div class="p-float"><div class="p-float-in">
 <center> <img class="p-img" src="IMAGES\horror.jpg" alt = "logo" onmouseover  = "popinfo()" id = "horror-img"> Text</h1><br/>
        <div class="p-name">Horror Fiction</div>

</center></div>

</div>
</div>

<div id = "horror-pop"> Horror Text </div>
```

CSS code

```
#horror-pop{
display: none;
}
```

JS Code

```
function popinfo(){

var e = document.getElementById("horror-img"); //get image from html

e.onmouseover = function() {
  document.getElementById('horror-pop').style.display = 'block';
}

e.onmouseout = function() {
  document.getElementById('horror-pop').style.display = 'none';
}   
}
```

You need to change the id for what you are calling for variable e.
Also, your html code tags are not properly closed center tag has to be closed first before you close divs outside of it.

For multiple images you can use if else assigning ids for all images and accordingly use JS in them or you can simply id them as a sequence so that u can identify them at once.

Comment: I put the script inside my HTML file and now it run

Answer (score 0):

Your element id is not img but you can try with class p-img.

Answer (score 0):

to make the code dynamic so tit can work for various images, do this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.p-img').forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
        popinfo(e, 'show');
    });

    element.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
        popinfo(e, 'hide');
    })
});
```

then you can modify your popinfo function to this:

```
function popinfo(element, action){

    if(action === 'show'){
        element.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        element.style.display = 'none';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var count = 0;
    $('#horror-img').mouseenter(function() {
        count++;
        $('.horror-pop').show();
    });

    $('#horror-img').mouseleave(function() {
        count--;
        if (count == 0) { 
            $('horror-pop').hide();
        }
    });
});
```